# Validar campo de formulario en request de laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

¿Cómo puedo validar que un campo del formulario solo permita texto?, es decir, no acepte número u otros carácteres diferentes a letras normales del alfabeto.

Supuse que con esto sería suficiente

```
"campo" => "required|string"
```

pero si digito el número 1 deja grabar en la base de datos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con la `validation` `string` admite Strings  y `"1"` lo es.

Pon [`alpha`](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-alpha) para que compruebe que es un texto *alpha*betico:

```
"campo" => "required|alpha"
```

Comment: ¡¡¡Excelente!!!

Comment: @SantiagoMuñoz me alegra ser de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: Pregunta ¿Esto acepta ñ?

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez yo diría que si

Answer (score 2):

Para qué esperar ir al backend a validarlo, si puedes validar desde el input con html5 de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="text"  pattern="^[a-z]{20}" title="solo acepto letras">
```

`[a-z]` aquí indicas que solo aceptas letras de la a a la z en minúscula.

`{20}` aquí indicas que aceptas 20 caracteres.

Comment: Esto no valida "ñ" ni tildes. y de donde sacas los 20 caracteres de extension? Ademas Pattern no funciona en Firefox ni en IE9 y anteriores

Comment: @lois6b yo le puse 20 como ejemplo pero le puedes poner menos o más, al igual que aquí [a-z] lo puedes poner así [A-Z] para que sea en mayúsculas. O combinado y aceptaría mayúsculas y minúsculas, ojo en él title describe específicamente cuál es la regla del input para que lo vean los usuarios.

Comment: en vez de `[a-zA-Z]` puedes poner `/i` para que no tenga en cuenta la capitalizacion. Ademas si pones `{20}` han de ser 20 caracteres, no max 20 caracteres. deberia ser `{1,20}`

Comment: Ajá, pues así úsalo. Para qué haces un request más al server si se puede solucionar desde el navegador. Saludos!

Comment: Usé validaciones de [tag:laravel] porque las etiquetas de la pregunta asi lo decian. no preguntó validacion por HTML. tu respuesta es valida, pero no me parece que se acerque a lo que el usuario esperaba. y recuerda que el atrributo `pattern` no admite todos los navegadores

Comment: @lois6b tiene razón, buen día.